# How to set line-space with Android Jetpack Compose Text()?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want to give more space `dp` between lines in the `Text()` content.  The only property I find is the `letterSpacing` of `TextStyle`, however, it doesn't seem as I want, can we set it with composing somehow?

Answer (score 43):

You can use the [**`lineHeight`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#text) property:

```
Text(text = "Hello Compose".repeat(50),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).width(200.dp),
    maxLines = 5,
    lineHeight = 50.sp
)
```

With `20.sp` and `50.sp`

[image]
[image]

or you can use the [**`TextStyle`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle.html):

```
Text(text = "Hello Compose".repeat(50),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).width(200.dp),
    maxLines = 5,
    style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(lineHeight = 50.sp)
)
```

Comment: can we set it in percentage? some designers in Figma use percentage

Comment: Call of `lineHeight` requires API level 28.

Answer (score 6):

I did it like this.

```
 Text(text = "Hello",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5.copy(
            lineHeight = 35.sp,  // Here line height 
        ),
  )
```

Or simply you can use lineHeight

```
   Text(text = "Hello",
            lineHeight = 35.sp
      )
```

> Caution: sp is case sensitive

Answer (score 2):

Hi try to change style property of TextView - TextStyle.lineHeight